# discord py how can i give a role to server member user with id

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

**Explanation about what my code does:** my code checks if a member on my server has the specific keyword "TEST" in her activity and gives a rank for it to the user. And if the keyword gets removed from the activity, the rank gets removed too. Offline members are not affected by this. So I had to save the member is in a file.

Now i have a problem:

```
await bot.guilds[0].get_member(int(member_id)).add_roles(role)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And thats my code:

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role = 773634102149775390
    file = open('role_members.txt', 'r')
    member_list = [str(member.id) for member in bot.get_all_members() if not str(member.status) == 'offline' and 'TEST' in str(member.activity)]
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[:-1] not in member_list:
            member = await bot.guilds[0].get_member(int(line))
            await member.remove_roles(role)
    a_file = open('role_members.txt', 'a')
    for member_id in member_list:
        await bot.guilds[0].get_member(int(member_id)).add_roles(role)
        a_file.write(member_id + '\n')
            
        
check_activity.start()
```

**How can I fix this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without files, simply get the guild using id. Then check for `guild.members` activities.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role_name = 'Test'
    guild = bot.get_guild(123456798)
    role = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name=role_name)
    for member in guild.members:
        try:  # if he is online.
            status = member.activities[0].name
            if role_name in status:
                await member.add_roles(role)
            else:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
        except:  # he is offline
            pass
```

Comment: The bot removes the rank every time the user goes offline, I don't want that. They should keep the rank, can you please help me with that?

Comment: And what must be the "seconds=120" time for giving the rank in a guild with 1.000 members? Because many members have the text in her custom status but doesn't get the rank.

Comment: Now it keeps the role, You should choose the best time you see fit `hours=` `minutes=` `seconds=`.

Comment: I have a problem, the "except" thing doesnt work correctly. Now users that remove his status with my specific keyword, they keep the rank.